# Object or non-object function property, What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, properties

by using "function(style)" it didn't work , but when using "function({style})" it worked, please explain why ?

the **Right** code:

```
export default function Title( { title } ) {
  return (
    <div className="section-title">
      <h4>{title}</h4>
      <div />
    </div>
  );
}
```

the **Wrong** code:

```
export default function Title( title ) {
  return (
    <div className="section-title">
      <h4>{title}</h4>
      <div />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional components get `props` **object** as argument.

With below line of code you are destructuring the `title` prop, which is **correct**.

```js
export default function Title( { title } )
```

Here below, you are receiving title as **object** and rendering it which is wrong because, in react you cannot render objects.

```js
export default function Title( title ) {
  return (
    <div className="section-title">
      <h4>{title}</h4>
      <div />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Another correct way is**

```js
export default function Title( props ) {
  return (
    <div className="section-title">
      <h4>{props.title}</h4>
      <div />
    </div>
  );
}
```